# Django and SQL Injection with example

Tags: django, security

I'm receiving an incoming POST from another site, below is how I currently get it. I'm new to Django, but few things jump out at me and I'm wondering if I should be concerned.

**SQL Injection:** As I cannot clean the post data is using `request.POST['message']` open is SQL injection? 
**Security:** is there a better way to do this?

```
@csrf_exempt
def incoming_message(request):
    if request.POST:
        # Match incoming keyword.
        keyword = Keyword.objects.get(keyword=request.POST['message'])
```

Comment: I don't understand what the concern is, django will do what's necessary to properly escape your input

Comment: My concern is SQL Injection, in other languages I have tried allowing direct filter etc without first cleaning the data is very bad and opens a big security flaw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django has built in [SQL injection prevention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) in its queryset driver.

> By using Django’s querysets, the resulting SQL will be properly escaped by the underlying database driver.

Because you're using a queryset, you're covered for SQL injection.  You may want to check that you're comfortable with the [XSS protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection) that Django provides.  Depending on how you use the data, you may need to escape it yourself.